# How to enable ligatures in FiraCode for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I downloaded the FiraCode font's and have selected that as my font in Visual Studio.  However the ligatures are not showing and the wiki doesn't have any special instruction for visual studio, although they imply it works because it is listed in their WORKS column for editor support.

https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/

Anyone have the missing step(s) to display the ligatures in visual studio 2015?

Comment: Did you close and restart Visual Studio? I ran into the same problem and this fixed it. See: https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/issues/112

Comment: That did the trick - I should have known to try that.

Comment: I only get ligatures for the comparison operators, and not for '->'. Why?

Comment: @drinck please add that as the answer.

Comment: @Scotty.NET added.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Before it will work you will need to close and restart Visual Studio.

I ran into the same problem and this fixed it ([details](http://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/issues/112))

Comment: First rule of troubleshoot, always restart first!

Answer (score 6):

After installing the font and restarting Visual Studio, it works for the most part. The way that Visual Studio handles tokenization in the syntax highlighting [breaks the ligatures containing dashes](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/issues/259) (such as `<!-- -->`).

Comment: I have the same problem with -> operators in C++