# Disable ligatures in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, fonts

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170649/how-to-enable-ligatures-in-firacode-for-visual-studio-2015) question that is about enabling ligatures in Visual Studio, which appears to be automatic.

However, I don't like ligatures, so I was wondering if it is possible to *disable* them. I can't find anything in VS2017 or VS2019.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some time ago Microsoft created "Cascadia Mono" font, which is the same font as default in Visual Studio, but without ligatures.

You can download "Cascadia Mono" font from here:
https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/releases

Install this font on your machine, restart Visual Studio, select "Cascadia Mono" font, and you will achieve the same result as "disabling" ligatures in VS.

Answer (score 10):

I also want to disable font ligatures in VS2017 today, then I found [this link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/536053/how-to-completely-disable-font-ligatures-feature-o.html) in MSDN community site. They say:

> Currently, Visual Studio doesn’t have the ability to disable font ligatures in the editor, so the only option you currently have available is to chose a font that doesn’t provide ligatures.

I think they are foolish about this.

Comment: Absolutely :-) The good thing is MS now also provides Cascadia Mono, which does not have ligatures. This font was the reason I posted this question in the first place.  https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code/releases

Answer (score 9):

I ran into that issue in VS2022 aswell when tried to install Jetbrains Mono font. But it occured that jetbrains provides same font without ligatures, it's name is followed by 'NL'

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if Visual Studio supports it but VSCode has this setting

```
"editor.fontLigatures": false
```

Comment: No the question is about visual studio, not vscode.